# How can you programatically disable Windows Update in XP using C#

Tags: c#, automation, windows-update

I am working on a project and need to automate disabling Windows Automatic Update using my C# code. I am not quite sure where to start. I have read about possibly using the Windows Update Agent API but am not sure. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are multiple other ways of doing this through group policies and what not - why does *your* code need to do it? This is just curiosity, not critique.

Comment: I am writing an installer package for a client that could possibly change some of the settings when updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a windows service that is responsible for performing the updates, you can stop this service with the following code:

```cs
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("wuauserv");
try
{
    if (sc != null && sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        sc.Stop();
    }
    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
    sc.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

You will need:

1. Add a reference to the proyect selecting "Add Reference" into Project Name then Add `System.ServiceProcess`
2. Include `using System.ServiceProcess;` in your class
3. Run your application or Visual Studio as Administrator

Comment: Would it be a similar fix if I need to run this on a remote client computer?

Comment: The code can be the same, but you would need to have the following rules for safety:
1. Computers must be in the same domain
2. You must have a domain user that has administrator permissions on the 2 Computers
3. You must start your application or Visual Studio with the domain user

If you meet the above, you could change the following line:

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController ("wuauserv", "RemoteMachineName");

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly achieve that by changing the Registry. Have a look at this technet page (should apply to Win XP as well as some others): 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939844(v=ws.10).aspx (Key: NoAutoUpdate)

There are some Classes which Help you accessing the Registry within C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.90).aspx

(Source: Google)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Having a look and testing out the code. Will let you guys know how it works out!